# Async Task below but for some reason it keeps saying that my JSON array cannot be applied to a JSONarray[]?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I created an Async Task below but for some reason it keeps saying that my JSON array cannot be applied to a `JSONarray[]`??? The error occurs in my `AsyncTask` in the `listblogs=parseJSONResponse(result)`; What is going on here?

```
class YourTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, String, ArrayList<Blogs> > {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Blogs> doInBackground(JSONArray... result) {
        listblogs.clear(); // here you clear the old data
        listblogs=parseJSONResponse(result);
        return listblogs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Blogs> blogs) {
        mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(listblogs);
    }
}



private void JsonRequestMethod() {
    final long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
            //intitalize Volley Singleton request key
            mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
            //2 types of requests an Array request and an Object Request
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    System.out.print(response);
                    listblogs = new YourTask().doInBackground();
                    listblogs.clear();
                             listblogs=parseJSONResponse(response);
                    try {
                        listblogs = new YourTask().execute().get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println(response);
                            Log.d("Testing", "Time elapsed: " + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start));
                    System.out.println("it worked!!!");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }

private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String points = currentQuestions.getString("points");
                String ID=currentQuestions.getString("id");
                String studentId = currentQuestions.getString("studentId");
                String DateCreated=currentQuestions.getString("created");
                long time=Long.parseLong(DateCreated.trim());
                data.append(text + "\n" + points + "\n");
                System.out.println(data);
                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setId(ID);
                blogs.setMstudentId(studentId);
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setPoints(points);
                //The dateCreated was off by 1 hour so 3600000 ms where added=1hour, (UPDATE)
                blogs.setDateCreated(getTimeAgo(time));
                System.out.println(time + "time");


                listblogs.add(blogs);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return listblogs;
}
```

stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                                       at com.athena.athena.MainActivitys.Dashboard$YourTask.doInBackground(Dashboard.java:129)
                                                                       at com.athena.athena.MainActivitys.Dashboard$YourTask.doInBackground(Dashboard.java:124)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: where is `parseJSONResponse` ? what type is `listblogs` ?

Comment: add your parseJSONResponse() implementation

Comment: Thank You for pointing that out I forgot to include it, It has been updated! and type listblogs is private ArrayList<Blogs> listblogs = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: listblogs is basically just a get and set method that holds the different strings and its an Arraylist

Comment: provide stack trace of error..

Comment: Please post you logcat error trace.

Comment: @eli: Seem the data you are getting is blank. Try to print it.

Comment: from which method you're calling the `execute()` method of this task..?? Also tell me where you declared the `listblogs` variable..is it local or global..

Comment: My JSONrequestionmethod

Comment: also post the calling code like `yourTaskObj.execute(someJsonArray)`...

Comment: is this not the same?    listblogs = new YourTask().execute().get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class YourTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, String, ArrayList<Blogs> > {
    ArrayList<Blogs> auxArrayList;
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Blogs> doInBackground(JSONArray... result) {
        auxArrayList=parseJSONResponse(result[0]);
        return auxArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Blogs> blogs) {
        mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(listblogs);
    }
}



private void JsonRequestMethod() {
    final long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
            //intitalize Volley Singleton request key
            mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
            //2 types of requests an Array request and an Object Request
            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    System.out.print(response);
                    try {
                        listblogs.clear();
                        listblogs = new YourTask().execute(response).get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println(response);
                            Log.d("Testing", "Time elapsed: " + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start));
                    System.out.println("it worked!!!");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }



private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    ArrayList<Blogs> myAuxArrayList = null;
    if (!response.equals("")) {

        try {
             myAuxArrayList = new ArrayList<Blogs>();
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String points = currentQuestions.getString("points");
                String ID=currentQuestions.getString("id");
                String studentId = currentQuestions.getString("studentId");
                String DateCreated=currentQuestions.getString("created");
                long time=Long.parseLong(DateCreated.trim());
                data.append(text + "\n" + points + "\n");
                System.out.println(data);
                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setId(ID);
                blogs.setMstudentId(studentId);
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setPoints(points);
                //The dateCreated was off by 1 hour so 3600000 ms where added=1hour, (UPDATE)
                blogs.setDateCreated(getTimeAgo(time));
                System.out.println(time + "time");


                myAuxArrayList.add(blogs);


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return myAuxArrayList;
}
```

Copy and paste and tell me if works pls

Comment: The myAuxArrayList is null for some reason

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray... = JSONArray[] , so take the first index. It will work
@Override
protected ArrayList<Blogs> doInBackground(JSONArray... args) {
    listblogs.clear(); // here you clear the old data
    listblogs=parseJSONResponse(args[0]); //Your error I think
    return listblogs;
}
Infact JSONArray... is not result, it is an argument to AsyncTask

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Blogs> result) {
    //handle result here
}
```

Comment: why did you include result[0]?

Comment: Did it crash with the same exception? or something new in some other line?

Comment: Check it, it must be NullPointerException, probably u r passing null argument

Comment: nope not a null pointer exception FATALEXCEPTION:syncTask #1
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

Replace this method with this

```
private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
ArrayList<Blogs> list = new ArrayList<Blogs>();
if (!response.equals("")) {
    try {
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
            String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
            String points = currentQuestions.getString("points");
            String ID=currentQuestions.getString("id");
            String studentId = currentQuestions.getString("studentId");
            String DateCreated=currentQuestions.getString("created");
            long time=Long.parseLong(DateCreated.trim());
            data.append(text + "\n" + points + "\n");
            System.out.println(data);
            Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
            blogs.setId(ID);
            blogs.setMstudentId(studentId);
            blogs.setMtext(text);
            blogs.setPoints(points);
            //The dateCreated was off by 1 hour so 3600000 ms where added=1hour, (UPDATE)
            blogs.setDateCreated(getTimeAgo(time));
            System.out.println(time + "time");


            list.add(blogs);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

return list;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `JSONArrayRequest` code

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            System.out.print(response);
            // never call AsyncTask's doInBackground() method like this
            //listblogs = new YourTask().doInBackground();
            //listblogs.clear();
            //listblogs=parseJSONResponse(response);
            try {
                // You were executing AsyncTask without passing any parameters.
                // change this line by this
                listblogs = new YourTask().execute(response).get();
                // I think this is the only cause
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(response);
                    Log.d("Testing", "Time elapsed: " + (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start));
            System.out.println("it worked!!!");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
```

Whenever you want to execute `AsyncTask`, you have to do `asyncTaskObject.execute(params)`.